# JSON keeping the existing content while writing new ones into it (txt file)

Tags: json

So im making this memory game and im trying to add a scoreboard and i want to write the data to a txt file using JSON. I got all of that to work but now i have a small issue, everytime i run my program the existing data in my txt file gets overwritten by the new data.

Here is the code that i use:

```
 public static void Score(String gamescore, string loginname)
    {
        List<Highscore> Myhighscores = new List<Highscore>();

        Myhighscores.Add(new Highscore { Score = gamescore, Name = loginname });
        string Jstr = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Myhighscores);
        File.WriteAllText(@"c:\temp\hs.txt", Jstr);               
    }
```

does anyone know how i can keep the existing data and also write the new data into the txt file?

Comment: why the tag jQuery?

Comment: cus i get all the data from jquery but i guess that is not important for this question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out my self all i needed to do is read the existing data like this:

```
string hs = File.ReadAllText(@"c:\temp\hs.txt");
```

and put it back into my list "Myhighscores" like this:

```
Myhighscores = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Highscore>>(hs);
```

> No thanks to Sagar V who just bitched that i put the jquery tag in.